# $\int gf \, d \lambda = 0$ for all continuous $g$ implies $f=0$ almost surely"

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis

Consider the following fragment from Murphy's book "$C^*$-algebras and operator theory" (p96: Toeplitz operators):

[image: ous]

**Question:**

Why do we have $$\forall g \in C(\Bbb{T}): \int fg \,d \lambda = 0 \implies f \, d \lambda = 0$$

Maybe we should use that $C(\Bbb{T})$ is dense in $L^1(\Bbb{T})$ together with DCT?

Comment: Your question is more or less a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2416568/if-int-fg-0-for-all-compactly-supported-continuous-g-then-f-0-a-e?rq=1)

Comment: Note my edits changing $f d \lambda$ to $f \, d\lambda.$ Similarly one writes $a\,dx\,dy$ rather than $a dx dy$ and $\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x\, \partial y}$ rather than $\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}$ and $f(x)\,\Delta x$ rather than $f(x) \Delta x,$ etc. $\qquad$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The map $$F: (L^\infty(\mathbb{T}, |f \, d\lambda|), \|\cdot\|_1) \to \mathbb{C}, \, g \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{T}} fg \, d\lambda$$ is a bounded linear functional and hence continuous since $$|F(g)| = \left|\int_{\mathbb{T}}  fg \, d\lambda \right| = \left|\int_{\mathbb{T}} g \, d(f\, d\lambda)\right| \leq \int_{\mathbb{T}} |g| \, d |f \, d\lambda| = \|g\|_1$$
where we used that for any bounded measurable $g: \mathbb{T} \to \mathbb{C}$ we have $$\int_{\mathbb{T}} fg \, d\lambda = \int_{\mathbb{T}} g \, d(f \, d\lambda).$$
Furthermore $C(\mathbb{T})$ is $\|\cdot\|_1$-dense in $L^\infty(\mathbb{T}, |f \, d\lambda|)$ and $F$ vanishes on $C(\mathbb{T})$, so we obtain $F = 0$. Now $g = \frac{\overline{f}}{|f|+1} \in L^\infty(\mathbb{T}, |f \, d\lambda|)$ and therefore $$0 = F(g) = \int_{\mathbb{T}} \frac{|f|^2}{|f|+1} \, d\lambda,$$
so $f = 0$ $\lambda$-almost everywhere.

More generally it can be shown that for a regular complex measure $\nu$ on a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ we have $$\int_X \phi \, d\nu = 0 \ \ \forall \phi \in C_c(X) \implies \nu = 0.$$
This is one component of the complex Riesz-Markov-Kakutani representation theorem, but the proof is analogous to the above since $C_c(X)$ is dense in $L^1(X, |\nu|)$.

Comment: Why is $F$ bounded?

Comment: I don't quite see this. We have $\Vert Fg\Vert \leq \Vert fg \Vert_1\leq \dots ??? <\infty$

Comment: You are right, I used the wrong space here. I updated my answer to give a correct solution.