# Show $\int f\phi = \int g \phi$ for all test functions $\phi$ implies $f=g$ for continuous $f$ and $g$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, proof-writing

> Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are continuous in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)\phi(x)dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g(x)\phi(x)dx, \forall\phi\in \mathcal{D}$$ implies that $f(x)=g(x),\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

All kinds of variants of this question have been asked on this site before, f.ex. [If $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f\phi=0$ for all continuous compactly supported $\phi$, then $f\equiv 0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593701/if-f-in-l1-mathbbr-is-such-that-int-mathbbrf-phi-0-for-all-contin) and [If $f\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\int f\varphi=0$ for all $\varphi$ continuous with compact support, then $f=0$ a.e.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2289484/if-f-in-l1-loc-mathbbr-and-int-f-varphi-0-for-all-varphi-continuo) . But what about simply continuous functions $f$ and $g$? Every continuous function is locally integrable, so by the proof provided in the second link (generalized to $\mathbb{R}^n$), we would have that $f-g=0$ a.e. in $L^1$. How do I actually show that $f=g$ *everywhere* in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Is there another way to prove this, without using local integrability?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous, $f-g$ is also continuous. By linearity, this means that you should verify whether $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)\phi(x)dx=0$ for all continuous compactly supported functions implies $f\equiv0$.

Assume $f(x_0)> 0$, then by continuity there exists a ball $B_\delta(x_0)$ such that $f(x)>\frac{1}{2}f(x_0)$ for all $x$  in said ball. There is also a ball $B_{\delta'}(x_0)\supsetneq B_{\delta}(x_0)$ for which $f(x)>0$. Take a continuous function $\phi$ such that $\phi_{B_\delta(x_0)}=1$ and $\phi_{\big( B_{\delta'}(x_0) \big)^c}=0$. Check the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)\phi(x)dx$.

Comment: Very elegant solution! As for the integral check: $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)\phi(x)dx=\int_{B_{\delta'}(x_0)} f(x)\phi(x)dx > \int_{B_{\delta}(x_0)} f(x)dx > \frac12 f(x_0) m(B_{\delta}(x_0)) > 0$, which contradicts the assumption, so $f=0$ everywhere on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The complement of a measure zero set in $\mathbb{R}$ is of course dense. So if $f-g$ is continuous and equal to $0$ on a dense set, it must be zero everywhere.